# Discussion Board Alert Me On Only New Items

Tags: discussion-board

We are on SP2013 and I only want an alert when a new discussion is added.  I choose "New items are added" for the change type but I don't want to be alerted whenever others keep making replies to the discussion.  Thanks.

Comment: do you only have one alert subscription? You may have an alert for both new items and one for changes.

Comment: Yeah, just one alert.  I created the discussion board and the alert right after for testing. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Alerts can be set for entire discussion boards and for individual discussions.

Perhaps the alert you're managing only applies to the individual discussion, not the greater discussion board (or vice-versa).

I recommend checking your alert subscriptions for the entire discussion board list.